# Python package structure: How to import auto-generated proto buf classes

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, proto

I have an API using protocol buffers which I want to wrap in a Python SDK. I auto generate Python class files from the proto buf definitions using [protoc](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python/). The package tree I currently have is

```
package_name/
    module_name/
        protocompiled/
            __init__.py
            endpoints.py
            messages.py
        main_stuff.py
```

The auto compiled file `endpoints.py` uses the `messages.py` file: It imports from it using `import messages`. However, given the package structure, this is not allowed, so when trying to do `import package_name.module.protocompiled.endpoints`, an error is thrown: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'messages'`

Is there any way to solve this? If I had been able to change the auto generated files, I could do `from . import messages`, but that's not an option because of the auto generation.

Comment: Have you tried with only `import protocompiled.endpoints`? Looking at an old project of mine, this seemed to work for me